# Complex layouts with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working in a web application using AngularJS + SpringMVC. I have some constraints as using pure HTML view pages, so, server-side frameworks as Tiles are not an option.

My gess is that angularJS `ng-view` tag is not powerfull enouth to develop complex layouts.

Could someone propose some client-side alternative to develop html layout templates?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To start, what's "complex" to you? Can you put up a screengrab of what you're attempting to achieve?

Comment: seems like all you've done is guess....angular doesn't care what your structure is and there are lots of ways to manipulate html in angular

Comment: @charlietfl, can angularJS manipulate nested views and view inheritance out of the box? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki) by the AngularUI team. It supports multiple views, nested views and inheritance for views. This definitely helped me creating more complex template structures.